# URL Loading Problem

Tags: iphone

I parsing the "http://feeds.epicurious.com/newrecipes" URL and i read the  URLs as following format.

http://feeds.epicurious.com/~r/newrecipes/~3/TGBDO1Ld400/361889

When i put this above Url in UIWebview, it does not work.

But When i put this URL in web browser it will change automatically as the following format.

http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Cherry-Cranberry-Sauce-361889?mbid=rss_epinr&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+newrecipes+%28Epicurious+-+New+Recipes%29

How to solve this issue. If anybody having any idea please answer me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get that same link to load with a stock iPad split view controller that only contained an outlet to a UIWebView named "viewer".  I called this code from viewDidLoad: in the root view controller:

```
[detailViewController.viewer loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feeds.epicurious.com/~r/newrecipes/~3/TGBDO1Ld400/361889"]]];
```

Hope that helps.